# Spring kafka consumer single batch pull is fetching data from different partitions

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We have 1 topic with 3 partitions with single consumer. We are consuming data as batches (25) using KafkaListener annotation of spring. Sometimes we are seeing in single pull of 25 messages is having data from different partitions.

Is it expected behaviour of spring ? If so how the commit works? Will spring take care of committing all partitions when we call acknowle() method with manual commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Spring, it's Kafka; that's how it works.

You have to acknowledge each message but, yes, the container will take care of the commits.

You can set `max.poll.records` to 1 if you only want a message from a single partition.

BTW, it's quite unusual to ack manually; it's generally preferred to let the container take care of the offsets using `AckMode.BATCH` or `AckMode.RECORD`.

Comment: Thank you Gary. When I tried with batch size 1 and manually acknowledging, I see few offsets were losted. I have one topic with 9 partitions. I am using kafka 0.10.2 and spring 1.2.2 version

Comment: You need to upgrade spring-kafka to 1.3.7 - it has a much simpler threading model, thanks to KIP-62. It will work with older brokers.

Comment: Thanks Gary. It worked with 1.2.2 version. But one open issue I have is,  when any runtime exception occurs I don't want that offset to be committed. I tried with ackonerror false, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please don't use 1.2.x, it is no longer supported; upgrade to at least 1.3.7; the current release is 2.1.10.

Comment: Thanks Gary. We don't have 1.3.7 . Can we use 1.3.5?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "we don't have" - it's in Maven Central. 1.3.5 is better than 1.2.x, but there are some bug fixes in 1.3.6 and 1.3.7.